# How does Java exception / Error handling work ? Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:

Tags: java, error-handling

I am new to java and trying to figure it out how can I use the exception in java. According to what I have read .. I can do something like..

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ElevatorFullException extends Exception {
    public ElevatorFullException() { super("Elevator is Full");}
}
```

Then use it in the program

```
  public void boardPassenger( int destinationFloorNumber ) 
           throws ElevatorFullException 
   {
       if ( passengerCount == CAPACITY )
       {
           throw new ElevatorFullException();
       }
       passengerLeaving[destinationFloorNumber - 1] += 1;      
       isDestination[destinationFloorNumber -1] = true;
       passengerCount += 1;
  }
```

My program ran fine without the exception , but one I add this exception it broke with this error below :

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Unhandled exception type ElevatorFullException**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In main:

```
try{
    boardPassenger(3);
}
catch(ElevatorFullException ee){
   //do any processing you need when exception is thrown
}
```

### If main cannot be changed:

```
public void boardPassenger( int destinationFloorNumber ) {
try{
            if ( passengerCount == CAPACITY ) {
                   throw new ElevatorFullException();
            }
            passengerLeaving[destinationFloorNumber - 1] += 1;      
        isDestination[destinationFloorNumber -1] = true;
        passengerCount += 1;
    }
    catch (ElevatorFullException ee){
       //do any processing you need when exception is thrown
    } }
```

Comment: That's a good solution. You have to catch it because it's not a RuntimeException. That's why you get the compiler error if you don't handle it.

Comment: @Soumyorup If the main() is in my test.java that I am not allowed to change anything in there. Is there another way for me to change it with in the class / method ?